# Horizontally centre div not working as expected

Tags: html, css

Encountering a new css problem I've never witnessed before. Simple enough, creating a modal like structure where the parent element is fixed with text align center like so:

```
.pro-gallery-wrapper {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
display: block;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 9999;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
text-align: center;
}
```

and it's child:`

```
.pro-gallery {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
display: inline-block;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: white;
max-height: 100%;
@include transform(translateY(-50%));
@include box-shadow(0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    max-width: em(768px);
}
@media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
    max-width: em(875px);
}
@media (min-width: 1589px) {
    max-width: em(1489px);
}
}
```

Now what happens is that the child centers, but instead of it's width spanning out from the center the left side of the div begins from the center and expands right.

This is a complete anomaly from other areas of the site where I've used the exact same technique. Any ideas?

http://hannahhamlin.co.uk/Projects/Final-Collection

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: http://hannahhamlin.co.uk/Projects/Final-Collection @Patrick

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS (and the necessary HTML to reproduce the problem)**.  We are not interested in looking at your entire page, we want a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add left: 50%; and to transform-x by -50% also

```css
.pro-gallery-wrapper {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
display: block;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 9999;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
text-align: center;
background: #f00;
}

.pro-gallery {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 500px;
display: inline-block;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: white;
max-height: 100%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pro-gallery-wrapper">
      <div class="pro-gallery">gallery goes here</div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: I've tried that and although it works, I begin get sizing issues at smaller screen widths, and also that wouldn't work on ie8. I don't see why text-align center isn't acting as it usually would

Comment: because of your position: absolute; top: 50%;

Comment: ie8 support is a bit ancient - if you must support it, I'd assume you have a separate stylesheet for it as you are already using transform.

Comment: Just add min-width or width for sizing on mobile.

Comment: I'm just going to have to accept that but the sizing doesn't respond at smaller widths very well as the child element's width need to size to the image inside that, but I suppose that's another question entirely. Thanks anyway